# Curl doesn't write on file cookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl, authentication

I'm trying to login to my website using curl all is working fine, the only problem is when I open the file cookie.txt I find it empty this is the code that I tried:

```
<?
$url = "http://security-dz.com/wp-login.php"; // URL
$POSTFIELDS = 'log=testtest&pwd=test1234';
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4)
Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

I created a file called cookie.txt at the same folder, but when I'm runing this code i can access my website normally the only problem is when i open the file cookie.txt it is empty so what i can do about this?

Comment: actually this si a good question, even me I'm stucked at the same problem i hope they answer it soon

Comment: `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options must be set with FULL (absolute) path value. `"cookie.txt"` is a relative path.

Comment: ...and `cookie.txt` must be writable by the user the web server runs as.

Comment: @hindmost but I so some tutorials they are putting it with the relative path !!

Comment: @user3395024 Just try to follow my advice and you'll see the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?
$url = "http://snipercoder.com/wp-login.php"; // URL
$POSTFIELDS = 'log=testtest&pwd=test1234';
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4)
Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "C:/yourfolderserver/www/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "C:/yourfolderserver/www/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get full path you can use this way to.

```
    $cookie=dirname(__FILE__)."\\cookie.txt";
```

so you can just use this way.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
```

it work for me

Answer (score 1):

`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options must be set with **absolute** path value. `"cookie.txt"` is a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a localhost try this:

```
<?
$url = "http://security-dz.com/wp-login.php"; // URL
$POSTFIELDS = 'log=testtest&pwd=test1234';
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4)
Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "C:/wamp/www/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "C:/wamp/www/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```